# question about how to feedback a bug,and I have a question about setting window

Tags: settings, display, pantheon

In system network proxy setting, the exception list do not have a scroll bar, and the setting window's min height depends on this list.
    How can I report this bug to developers? I don't know which project on github I should create a issues to?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed quite difficult, but it also makes somewhat sense since there are so many components that make an OS.

All parts specifically made for Elementary should be hosted under their Github organization: https://github.com/elementary.
"Pages" of system settings (the [switchboard](https://github.com/elementary/switchboard) project) are called "plugs", the networking plug for example is: 
https://github.com/elementary/switchboard-plug-networking